# InfluxDB mathematics across measurements

Tags: influxdb

I have two measurements in my InfluxDB, say, `mem_used` and `mem_ available`.
I tried to query across those measurements and do a mathematics with

```
SELECT mean("mem_used_value") / mean("mem_available_value") FROM 
    (
     SELECT mean("value") AS "mem_used_value", 
            mean("value") AS "mem_available_value"
     FROM "dbname"."autogen"."mem_used",
          "dbname"."autogen"."mem_available"
     GROUP BY time(1m)
    )
GROUP BY time(1m)
```

The result of the query is very weird, and I was wondering if it’s possible for InfluxDB to perform a mathematics across measurements.

I have did some research about this feature and found the issue [3552 Mathematics across measurements](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/3552) is still opening. However, it was requested three years ago.

Is there any approach to do this? any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no JOINs in Influx QL.

Remember pls: that's NOT a relational DB, the query language may look familiar, but it is a totally different thing.

Here's what you can do.

**1)** The smartest & legit-iest way: shape your measurement properly.

Currently you didn't: there should not be two measurements, but one, like (in [line protocol](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/write_protocols/line_protocol_tutorial/) notation)

```
memusage,host=yourhost,othertag=something,yetanotertag=anything mem_used=123,mem_available=321 yourtimestamp
```

**2)** Use [Kapacitor](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/) to join your measurements altogether.

There, you can do math right in Kapacitor, or simply write the result of the join back into a single measurement and later do your aggregations in plain InfluxQL.

Comment: That's very helpful, I will improve my measurement shaping. Thanks.